# Extend MUI palette with typescript, to be able to map through the palette with indexing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

**Currently I have a bigger problem when using the `Material UI Palette` in connection with Typescript. Unfortunately MUI v5.0 is not very well documented here. In addition, you also need deep `typescript` knowledge.**

*The goal is to map through the `palette` and to have all the colours virtually displayed. To do this, I first have to assign a correct Typescript type to the palette. However, I get a typescript error when mapping. He wont accept the `color prop` (see code) as an wright index key*

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'PaletteOptions'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'PaletteOptions'.ts(7053)
```

I understand the problem, but don't know how to solve it. Because type string should actually be the correct one.

*Everything works.
The logic is right. Unfortunately, I can't get rid of the type error*

palette.ts

```
import { Color } from '@mui/material';
import { PaletteOptions as MuiPaletteOptions } from 
'@mui/material/styles/createPalette';

export interface CustomMuiPalette extends MuiPaletteOptions {
  yellow: Partial<Color>;
  purple: Partial<Color>;
  border: {
    default: string;
  };
}

export const palette: CustomMuiPalette = {
  primary: {
    light: '...',
    main: '...',
    dark: '...',
  },
  secondary: {
    light: '...',
  .....
error: {
....
ans so one
};
```

// I also tried to declare new key types

```
  declare module '@mui/material/styles/createPalette' {
  interface TypeText {
    primary: string
    secondary: string
   ...
  }
```

Palette.tsx

```
interface PaletteProps {
  color: string;
  variants: string[];
}

export const Palette = ({ color, variants, ...props }: PaletteProps) => {
 const variantOptions =
typeof variants === 'object' ? Object.keys(variants) : variants;
....

  variantOptions.map((variant, index) => (
... <Box style={{ backgroundColor: palette[color][variant] }} /> // I am getting the error here, cause color is not accepted as an index key
```

MapPalette.tsx

```
import {palette} from ".."

const paletteOptions = Object.entries(palette);

...

{paletteOptions.map(([shade, variants], index) => (
      <Palette
        shade={shade}
        variants={variants}
        key={index}
      ></Palette>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you want to show all shades of your color palette to UI,
but you can't do this like that because Mui palette has more than just one type of color option and you need those with the type of `Partial<Color>` as you mentioned above, so here is what you have to do :

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles'
import { Box, Color } from '@mui/material'

declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  export interface PaletteOptions {
    paletteColors: {
      [key: string]: Partial<Color>
    }[]
  }
  export interface Palette {
    paletteColors: {
      [key: string]: Partial<Color>
    }[]
  }
}

export const Theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: 'dark',
    primary: {
      main: '#0D83DA',
      light: '#F3F4F5',
      dark: '#191C1F'
    },
    secondary: {
      light: 'rgba(66, 133, 255, 0.22)',
      main: 'rgba(29, 161, 242, 1)'
    },
    paletteColors: [
      {
        yellow: {
          '50': '#EADDCA',
          '100': '#EADDCA',
          '200': '#FBCEB1',
          '300': '#F5F5DC',
          '400': '#E1C16E',
          '500': '#FFEA00'
        }
      },
      {
        green: {
          '50': '#7CFC00',
          '100': '#7FFF00',
          '200': '#ADFF2F',
          '300': '#006400',
          '400': '#008000',
          '500': '#228B22',
          '600': '#00FF00'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
})

const Test = () => {
  const { palette } = Theme
  const { paletteColors } = palette

  return (
    <Box sx={{ m: '120px', p: '120px' }}>
      {paletteColors.map(color => {
        return Object.entries(color).map(variant => {
          const [colorName, colorShades] = variant
          return (
            <Box sx={{ m: 1, border: 'solid red 1px' }}>
              <Box sx={{ height: 30 }}>{colorName}</Box>
              {Object.entries(colorShades).map(shades => {
                const [shadeNumber, shadeVal] = shades
                return <Box sx={{ backgroundColor: shadeVal }}> {shadeNumber} </Box>
              })}
            </Box>
          )
        })
      })}
    </Box>
  )
}

export default Test
```

Comment: Thanks @ali mirzaei. But that still does not solve my typ problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8718230/ali-mirzaei

Comment: can you log this variable `paletteOptions`?

Comment: It is not possible to log PaletteOptions, since its a type

Comment: I tried your solution, but it did not work for my index issue. I have also declared the type of `TypeText`. That type is defining the key index types and it is from MUI. I have defined every key as a string, but that did not help. Typescript is still complaining. stackoverflow.com/users/8718230/ali-mirzaei

Comment: stackoverflow.com/users/8718230/ali-mirzaei  you can see what I mean in my updated post

Comment: I just updated my answer hope this works